# Correct way to retrieve a single object from Realm database in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, realm

```
#import "RLMObject.h"

@interface Product : RLMObject

@property NSInteger productId;
@property NSString *name;

@end

@implementation Product

+ (NSString *)primaryKey {
    return @"productId";
}

@end
```

fetch all objects:

```
RLMResults<Product *> *xx = [Product allObjects];
```

but how to get single object (not array) by its primary key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any RLMObject subclasses inherits method

- (nullable instancetype)objectForPrimaryKey:(nullable id)primaryKey;

So, you can fetch a single object by calling:

```
[Product objectForPrimaryKey: @""];
```